# Is it valid HTML to add a link to a fieldset legend?

Tags: html

Is it valid HTML to add a link to your legend tag? Like:

```
<fieldset>
<legend><span>Option A</span><span><a href="">Click to copy</a></span></legend> 
some text
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Why don't you validate it and see?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check says `This document was successfully checked as HTML 4.01 Strict!`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is according to the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org). And from an [accessibility point of view](http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2007/11/fieldsets-legends-and-screen-readers/), I see no problem in having a link in a [`fieldset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/fieldset.html) [`legend`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/legend.html) either, so you're good to go.